# How can I change the content of a xaml page when a user clicks on a radio button? C# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, openweathermap

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am developing a weather application using the Universal Windows Platform.

I am also using openweathermap to collect my weather data and Json.Net to parse the Json data that the api returns.

I have designed my app with a [navigation pane](https://maximelabelle.wordpress.com/2016/02/02/building-a-hamburger-menu-for-your-universal-app/) using a split view control and a frame.

Inside of the frame I have placed a relative panel. In the xaml code I have provided you can see the content I would like to place inside of the frame when the user clicks on the radio button.

What I need to do is fill out the function named CurrentWeather_Checked, it's currently empty, but I am not sure what I need to put in there to get the behavior that I want.

1.MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="Susanoo.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Susanoo"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ThemesGeneric.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ThemesText.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>
    <SplitView x:Name="NavigationPane" DisplayMode="CompactInline">
        <SplitView.Pane>

            <Grid>

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="44" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemButtonStyle}" Tag="&#xE700;" Click="HamburgerButton_Click" />

                <StackPanel x:Name="NavigationMenu" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF42424C">
                    <RadioButton x:Name="Option1"
           GroupName="Group1"
           Style="{StaticResource NavigationButtonStyle}"
           Tag="&#xE753;"
           Checked="CurrentWeather_Checked"
           Content="Current Weather"
           />
                    <RadioButton x:Name="Option2"
           GroupName="Group1"
           Style="{StaticResource NavigationButtonStyle}"
           Tag="&#xE909;"
           Checked="Option2Button_Checked"
           Content="Favorite Cities"
           />

                </StackPanel>

            </Grid>

        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>

            <Frame x:Name="Content" Background="#FF31A877">
                <Frame.ContentTransitions>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <NavigationThemeTransition>
                            <NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                                <EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo/>
                            </NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                        </NavigationThemeTransition>
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </Frame.ContentTransitions>
                <RelativePanel x:Name="contentDisplay">
                 <TextBlock x:Name="cityName" Style="{StaticResource displayText}" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" Text="City"/>
                 <TextBlock x:Name="countryName" Style="{StaticResource displayText}" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.Below="cityName" Text="Country"/>
                 <TextBlock x:Name="currentTemp" Style="{StaticResource displayText}" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True" Text="Temp"/>
                 <TextBlock x:Name="minTemp" Style="{StaticResource smallDisplayText}" RelativePanel.LeftOf="countryName" RelativePanel.Below="currentTemp"  Text="Min"/>
                 <TextBlock x:Name="maxTemp" Style="{StaticResource smallDisplayText}" RelativePanel.RightOf="countryName"  RelativePanel.Below="currentTemp"  Text="Max"/>
                </RelativePanel>
            </Frame>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
</Page>


 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
    using Windows.Foundation;
    using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
    using Windows.UI;
    using Windows.UI.Core;
    using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
    using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

    namespace Susanoo

    {
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {


            this.InitializeComponent();
            ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
            // Set the min size to 550 * 600
            ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size { Width = 550, Height = 600 });
            getCurrentWeather();
            TitleBar();
        }
        async void getCurrentWeather()
        {
            WeatherObject currentWeather = new WeatherObject();

            //units in Fahrenheit by default
            currentWeather.Units = "Imperial";

            //Searcy default for testing
            currentWeather.RootObject.Name = "Searcy";
            currentWeather.ZipCode = "72149";
            await currentWeather.Task_getWeatherInfoByCityName();
            //await currentWeather.Task_getWeatherInfoByZipCode();

            if (currentWeather.RootObject != null)
            {

                cityName.Text = currentWeather.RootObject.Name;
                countryName.Text = currentWeather.RootObject.Sys.Country;
                currentTemp.Text = currentWeather.RootObject.Main.Temp.ToString();
                if (currentWeather.Units == "Imperial")
                {
                    currentTemp.Text = Math.Floor(currentWeather.RootObject.Main.Temp).ToString() + "° F";
                    minTemp.Text = "Low: " + Math.Floor(currentWeather.RootObject.Main.Temp_Min).ToString() + "°";
                    maxTemp.Text = "High: " + Math.Floor(currentWeather.RootObject.Main.Temp_Max).ToString() + "°";
                }
                else if (currentWeather.Units == "Metric")
                {
                    currentTemp.Text = Math.Floor(currentWeather.RootObject.Main.Temp).ToString() + "° C";
                    minTemp.Text = "Low: " + Math.Floor(currentWeather.RootObject.Main.Temp_Min).ToString() + "°";
                    maxTemp.Text = "High: " + Math.Floor(currentWeather.RootObject.Main.Temp_Max).ToString() + "°";
                }

                //to use the images from openweathermap API
                //not sure how to actually get it to show in the image in the main page?
                string iconName = currentWeather.RootObject.Weather[0].Icon;
                string imgUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + iconName + ".png";
                //image.Source = imgUrl;
            }
        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs args)
        {
            // Page was navigated to
            var navManager = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
            if (this.Frame.CanGoBack)
            {
                // Show Back button in title bar
                navManager.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                // Remove Back button from title bar
                navManager.AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs args)
        {
            // Page is being navigated away from
        }

        private void aboutButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(AboutPage));
        }

        private void TitleBar()
        {
            ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
            titleBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.Black;
            titleBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.White;
            titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Black;
            titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.White;
        }
        public Frame AppFrame { get { return Content; } }

        private void CurrentWeather_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Here is where I am expecting I need to put the code
        }

        private void Option2Button_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void HamburgerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationPane.IsPaneOpen = !NavigationPane.IsPaneOpen;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You will be far better off using MVVM (and binding `IsChecked` instead of handling the `Checked` event). In that case, you will typically bind your radio buttons to types/instances of types so you can set the `Content` property of a `Content` control. Alternatively, use `Page` objects and just navigate when the buttons are clicked

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Could you please give me a code example? Because I am not very familiar with the MVVM pattern. @BradleyDotNET

Comment: Such an example would be far too extensive. Googling: "navigation with mvvm stackoverflow" gives some pretty good places to start

Comment: Please detail what behaviour that you want to  'put in there to get the behavior'. Also, it will be much better if you can upload the project.